# Probability for winning the game

Tags: statistics

If the odds for a baseball team to lose their next game are given as 9 to 5, then what is the implied probability that this team wins their next game?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds of $9:5$ implies a probability of $\frac{1}{9+5} \cdot 9 \approx 0.6429$.

$\therefore$ probability of winning $= 1-0.6429 \approx 0.3571$.

You could also do it more easily: if their odds of losing are $9:5$, then their odds of winning are $5:9$, and $\frac{1}{9+5} \cdot 5 \approx 0.3571$.